Issue Sending Large Custom Waveforms to Function Generator via TCP using socket
I'm trying to send large custom waveforms (up to 50,000 data points) to a Function Generator over a TCP connection. While smaller waveforms (up to 200 data points) are transmitted correctly, larger waveforms either do not write properly or only partially write to the EMEMory.
When attempting to send large waveforms, the waveform generator loads the previous waveform instead of the new one. This suggests an issue with the sendall command, which doesn't seem to handle the large data size effectively.
I think the problem lies within the socket.socket.sendall() function. If I understand correctly, the command should be long enough to write the entire buffer. However, as soon as I use this function for more than 250 points something goes wrong.
Here is the SCPI protocol i am using. https://files.owon.com.cn/software/Application/XDG_Waveform_Generator_SCPI_Protocol.pdf
relevant code snippet:
def load_waveform(self, waveform):
        """
        Load a custom waveform into the function generator.
        """
        waveform = np.round(waveform)
        waveform = [int(val) for val in waveform]

        data = bytearray()
        for val in waveform:
            data.extend(val.to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True))

        byte_count = len(data)
        header = f"#{len(str(byte_count))}{byte_count}".encode()

        chunk_size = 20  # Sending data in larger chunks for efficiency
        start_time = time.time()

        try:
            self._connection.sendall(b"DATA:DATA EMEMory," + header)
            for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
                self._connection.sendall(data[i:i + chunk_size])
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error loading waveform: {e}")

Things that i alrerady tried that didnt work out:

Chunk Size and Delays: Introduced a small delay between sending each chunk of data to avoid overloading the buffer.

retries in case of partial sends or errors (resending chunks)

Added a delay after sending the header to ensure it's processed before sending the actual data.



There's not really a question here. Also, you have a list of 3 items at the end, and your code example does none of these, so what's this list for?

Thank you for your reply. I have tried to formulate the question more clearly and provide additional information.

You should really have an application-layer protocol for this.
